# how do i put the address of the stack onto a1?

Tags: assembly, riscv

I know that the register `sp` holds the stack. How do I load the address of the stack onto a1? Is it just `add a1, x0, sp`?

Comment: what happened when you tried it?

Comment: Same way you copy any other register.